# Space in list despite using delimiters and how to remove it?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am solving project Euler problem 22, wherein the program reads a text file having text format as follows and then tries to alphabetically sort it:

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER",
"MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA", etc...
```

I use delimiter to eliminate both `""` and `","`, however when the ArrayList is sorted, it gives first element blank and sort result is like this:

```
<I get blank space here>,ANNALISA, ANNAMAE, ANNAMARIA, ANNAMARIE,
ANNE, ANNELIESE, ANNELLE, ANNEMARIE, ANNETT, ANNETTA, ANNETTE,
ANNICE, ANNIE, ANNIKA, ANNIS, ANNITA, ANNMARIE, ANTHONY,
ANTIONE, ANTIONETTE, ANTOINE, ANTOINETTE, etc...
```

My code is

```
public class Problem22 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("file.txt"));
        scan.useDelimiter(",|\"| ");

        String name = null;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            name = scan.next();
            names.add(name);
        }

        scan.close();

        Collections.sort(names);
        System.out.println(names);
}
   }
```

I need help to understand the reason for getting the blank line. Also I tried to remove it but unable to do it.

Comment: maybe there is a blank space at the end of the file and through sorting it gets placed at the first spot

Comment: You can execute .trim() for each name you read.  Probably, the source where you're reading from has spaces.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] please? Something with a minimal and also complete input that reproduces the issue. Preferable even as `String` inside the method (you can read from `String`s using `Scanner`). At the moment we can just guess where the space comes from. It's probably a **minor issue** somewhere in your input data.

Comment: Do you actually have a space there, or is it just an empty element (nothing before the comma)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Pattern b = Pattern.compile("\\|"+"\r\n");
        scan.useDelimiter(b);
```

I changed regex 

To understand the regular expression(regex)1:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html  
2:https://regexone.com/    - practice online

Comment: Why does this solve the issue? Please always pair code with explanation.

Comment: Why do you believe a pipe delimiter at the end of a line is applicable here?

Comment: if you meet line that begins with <blank> remove the blank and the new line. or yourWord.replaceAll("\n ", " ");

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code I actually had multiple empty strings in the result. Your mistake is your delimiter regex. `,|\"|` means "split at **each** `,`, `"`, or " and not "split at **sequences of** `,`, `"`, ".

That means that `"aaa", "bbb"` will be split into `["", "aaa", "", "", "", "", "bbb", ""]`.

Change your regex accordingly and it'll work. I used **`\\W+`** (meaning "sequences of non-word characters"), which also dealt with line breaks nicely. If you need more control, use something like `[, \"]+`.